# Difference between thermal and contact aureole

Tags: petrology

Are therms "***contact aureole***" and "***thermal aureole***" synonyms?

I found some sentence at A. M. PATWARDHAN (2012):

> "The peripheral extent up to which the thermal effect of the intrusion
>   is observed is referred to as the contact or thermal aureole of the
>   intrusive body."

Answer (score 3):

***Contact aureole***, ***thermal aureole*** and ***metamorphic aureole*** are all synonyms referring to the peripheral aureole of recrystallized rocks around an intrusion of an igneous body due to the heat flux between the intrusion and the box rock.

You can read several examples quoting both terms as synonyms:

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphism#Contact_(thermal)) article on metamorphic types includes a section heading of

> "Contact (thermal)"

And another example is [frontiersin.org](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/feart.2017.00082/full) where the subject regularly interchanges the terms to prevent monotony in the writing.